# How do i fill my table with data from 3 different tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I am working on a football world cup database. These are my important tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Countries(
   Cid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   Name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Stadiums(
   Sid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   Name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
   Cid INT REFERENCES Countries NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Groups(
   Gid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   Name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
   TYear SMALLINT REFERENCES Tournaments NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Teams(
   Tid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   Cid INT REFERENCES Countries NOT NULL,
   Gid INT REFERENCES Groups NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Matches(
   Mid INT PRIMARY KEY,
   HomeTid INT REFERENCES Teams NOT NULL,
   VisitTid INT REFERENCES Teams NOT NULL,
   HomeScore SMALLINT NOT NULL,
   VisitScore SMALLINT NOT NULL,
   MatchDate DATE NOT NULL, 
   MatchType VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
   Sid INT REFERENCES Stadiums NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE tempmatches( 
   year INTEGER, 
   host_country VARCHAR(255), 
   match_id INTEGER, 
   type VARCHAR(255), 
   date DATE, 
   location1 VARCHAR(255), 
   team1 VARCHAR(255), 
   team2 VARCHAR(255), 
   score1 INTEGER, 
   score2 INTEGER 
);
```

so my current problem is that I need to populate the columns HomeTid and VisitId of the Matches table with the tid's from the team's table that corresponds with the country of that team from the countries table but I'm not sure how to do that. I tried a few queries but none of them seemed to work. Has anyone an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I guess you wants to populate data in table "Matches". If so, please provide some sample output data for your table.

Answer (score 0):

Using JOIN keyword you can combine 2 tables data.
Here, in this case, you have to use 3-way join.

Eg:

3-way JOIN can be used in this way:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.col1=table2.col2 JOIN table3 ON table3.col3=table.col1;
```

Here the 2 tables will get joined based on the columns mentioned after the "ON" keyword.

Here is a reference link in which JOIN is explained clearly
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use JOIN operation. In SQL it helps to combine several tables(queries) in one